# Blender modeling - aligning faces

Tags: modeling, faces

After some scaling and extrusion, I see the attached asymmetry with faces. How can I align them?

[image]

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you want to achieve? Do you want to get rid of the triangles?

Comment: Yes, I want to get rid of the 4 triangles below and 2 quadrilaterals above them. In their place I want to add faces that are aligned with the other faces, which means I want the dots/points on the faces to align.

Comment: the easiest way would most likely be to delete all of the faces in those two "columns", but leave the vertices center vertices at the top and bottom, then extrude one of them(top one for example) and merge the extruded vertice with bottom one. then create faces by selecting the sides and pressing shift f